# Is there a way with Spring Boot and Hibernate to batch insert entities with UUID primary keys, using postgres?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

So I've done my homework as far as I know. I know auto generated keys cannot be inserted. But how do I get around this for primary keys that are a UUID?

I have this primary key configuration

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private UUID id;
```

I was hoping this was not considered an 'AUTO' strategy but it seems it is, because my entities are still being inserted individually, wrecking my performance with 10k inserts. Why could this not be considered a sequence strategy? The UUIDs are guaranteed unique anyway so there shouldn't be anything technical in the way of just generating a number of UUIDs and batch inserting them.

I do have the appropriate settings in my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

And I do use a `PagingAndSortingRepository`'s method `saveAll` to save the entities.

Some logs:

```
03:12:01.122 |  INFO | o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener | Session Metrics {
    35000 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    1533100 nanoseconds spent preparing 8 JDBC statements;
    49660800 nanoseconds spent executing 5 JDBC statements;
    5137013700 nanoseconds spent executing 401 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    6933591600 nanoseconds spent executing 2 flushes (flushing a total of 60152 entities and 40294 collections);
    244354300 nanoseconds spent executing 5 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 60009 entities and 60009 collections)
}
```

Which is interesting because it does mention batches. However, with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` enabled I see several thousands of log lines like the following:

`Hibernate: insert into ingestion_id_mapping (derive_ingestion_id, ingestion_id, project_id, metric_id, subject_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Which doesn't seem to correlate with the number in the batching stats.

Comment: Batching problem is not related to AUTO strategy but IDENTITY one. AUTO in this case should use the UUIDGenerator. Do you have some logs ? which version of PG and hibernate are you using ?

Comment: @CodeScale I'm using PostgreSQL 13 (locally anyway) and Hibernate that comes with Spring Boot 2.5.0, bleeding edge basically. I did some more experimenting with another entity that has an @ EmbeddedId in the form of 2 foreign UUID keys, but then even before the insert it started retrieving individual rows by those UUIDs. That's when I decided to give up and just use SQL INSERT INTO. Too much magic that I can't debug.

Comment: Do you some logs ? Like the one generated by `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true` property

Comment: @CodeScale I ran it again with that logging enabled now. Confusing results however.

Answer (score 2):

Replicating your sample [as follows](https://github.com/fladdimir/so-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/demo/batchinsert/BatchInsertTest.java), it actually seems to work as expected, assuming that the `reWriteBatchedInserts` jdbc connection property is set:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?reWriteBatchedInserts=true
```

Using e.g. with `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=8`, a corresponding postgres log would look like this one when inserting 8 newly created entities via `repository.saveAll`:

```
postgres_db_1  | 2021-06-02 15:22:54.327 UTC [386] LOG:  
  execute <unnamed>: /* insert org.demo.batchinsert.UuidEntity */
  insert into uuid_entity (id) values ($1),($2),($3),($4),($5),($6),($7),($8)
...
```

Comment: Insert statements seem to be batched in multiples of 2, so when needing e.g. 7 inserts, the executed inserts would insert 4, 2, and 1 value(s) at a time (which might seem confusing when looking at the db logs)

Comment: Well that's an interesting postgres option anyway, thanks. Unfortunately as is often the case, simple examples don't show the issue. Perhaps it's a combination of various entities in my project that's causing this.

Comment: reWriteBatchedInserts is to speed up performance at database side but it is only relevant if the client send statements in batch... if not this doesn't have any effect at all....

Answer (score 1):

Well actually you can't really say if batching is working just by looking at hibernate logs.

You have to proxy the `JDBC Driver` or the `Datasource` with tool like P6Spy. Then you'll probably see that batching is actually working.

You can use this decorator for that : https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator.

Now if you want to speed up the batch processing on the database side too the property `reWriteBatchedInserts` might be used.